# ImportError: No module named downsample

Tags: python, module, theano

I am using Theano. The OS is Ubuntu. The Theano is UPTODATE. I am wondering why I am getting by `from theano.tensor.signal.downsample import max_pool_2d` command.

`ImportError: No module named downsample`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `downsample` module has been moved to `pool`, so try declaring it as:

```
from theano.tensor.signal.pool import pool_2d
```

After changing delete your theano cache with the command:

```
theano-cache purge
```

Comment: `theano-cache purge
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    theano-cache purge
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Try doing the following ( [code here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/afa341ef477eb95a1ebcda44f7f967b6) ) to find the location of the cache, that's what you'll want to delete to make sure the imports are updated.

Comment: Thank you. It gives me an address. What is the next?

Comment: You'll want to delete the contents, as it's the cache which contains outdated imports.

Comment: Thank you. Now. `ImportError: No module named Theano.tensor.signal.pool`

Comment: It should be **lowercase** "theano", not "Theano". As a test try doing the following: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8a65c27f4e65e0ed5ad8ce124dab36af

Comment: ^ did you try lowercase "theano"? If the error persists then you must not have a completely current version -- `sudo pip install --upgrade --no-deps theano`

Answer (score 8):

update theano and lasagne

```
pip install --upgrade https://github.com/Theano/Theano/archive/master.zip
pip install --upgrade https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/archive/master.zip
```

[Lasagne vs Theano possible version mismatch (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998355/lasagne-vs-theano-possible-version-mismatch-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Try to update the Theano using this link.

```
pip install --upgrade https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/archive/master.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

Same issue [theano v.0.9.0dev1.dev-2...]; changed

```
from theano.tensor.signal import downsample
pooled_out = downsample.max_pool_2d( ... )
```

to

```
from theano.tensor.signal import pool
pooled_out = pool.pool_2d( ... )
```

in /lib/python2.7/site-packages/lasagne/layers/pool.py