# Cannot import anything from lasagne-0.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, lasagne

I have just installed both Theano and Lasagne using conda for Theano and pip for Lasagne. Both reside in subdirectories under " C:\Users\chets\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Lib\site-packages". The following code works:

```
import theano
```

The following code does not:

```
import lasagne
```

The error message for the latter is:
"import lasagne
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\chets\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5612/2601130582.py", line 1, in 
import lasagne

File "c:\Users\chets\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\lasagne_*init*_.py", line 19, in 
from . import layers

File "c:\Users\chets\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\lasagne\layers_*init*_.py", line 7, in 
from .pool import *

File "c:\Users\chets\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\lasagne\layers\pool.py", line 6, in 
from theano.tensor.signal import downsample

ImportError: cannot import name 'downsample' from 'theano.tensor.signal' (c:\Users\chets\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\signal_*init*_.py)"

Comment: Maybe you have a Theano version where `downsample` is not in `theano.tensor.signal`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39501251/5231110)? In that case maybe the Lasagne version doesn't match the Theano version. Try installing both as per the Lasagne documentation, for example.

Answer (score 0):

checked in Colab ,was getting different but similar error .Then ,I followed instructions from their [lasagne github](https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne) link after which it vanished .Here is the proper way install to lasagne

```
pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/master/requirements.txt
pip install https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/archive/master.zip
```

attaching [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/mohantym/080bc316bbdb2df9a7d0fd3361aafbd8/stack_68719388.ipynb#scrollTo=N-o-_IfcAhk_) for reference.